# Second derivative of a set in non-Fréchet space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In Fréchet (T1) topological spaces it's easy to prove that $A''\subseteq A'$, but the proof doesn't work without this assumption. What are some illuminating counterexamples when the space is not Fréchet?

Comment: An indiscrete two-point space.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielFischer, you're obviously right and I'm wondering how that example eluded me.  

However, there is something I'd find even more illuminating: a example whereby the space is Kolmogorov (T0).